# Lync Mobility and users homed on an SBA

Tags: lync

A client has found that Lync 2010 Mobility does not work for users homed on SBAs. This seems reasonable (although very annoying) because the appropriate services are not on the SBA server. This is actually a major problem for Mobility in Enterprise Voice scenarios because the best practice is to home users on their local SBA to allow voice support in the event of a central site loss, so following best practices leads to mobility not being available.

I have three questions around this:

1. Is this statement accurate? If so, where is there an official Microsoft statement around this restriction? I'm only aware of unofficial sources and the client would like something from MS directly if possible.
2. Is it supported to install the mobility services on SBAs?
3. Does Lync 2013 change anything around this specific area?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a SBA??

Comment: Survivable Branch Appliance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you are correct. Let the users be homed in SBA
2. No, we cannot install Mobility services in SBA. However Mobility is supported for SBA users as the HTTPS traffic will hit one the Front End servers IIS in a Pool which will authenticate the SBA homed user and get signed in
3. There is no change as far as I know. Still the Lync front end server is going to authenticate the SBA homed user